# searching for closest number in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, conditional-statements

Give two parameters which correspond to two attributes on an object how can one find 20 records in a database that are closest to those two numbers.

The parameters you have are x, and y. The object also has those attributes. For example. x = 1, and y = 9999. You need to find the record that is the closest to x and y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on how you define the distance between two points.  If you are using a two-dimensional cartesian coordinate system, this SQL statement will work:

```
SELECT id, x, y FROM points ORDER BY SQRT(POWER((X-x),2)+POWER((Y-y),2)) ASC LIMIT 20;
```

Where X,Y are the inputs.

Comment: +1 as this is exactly what I was going to post. My assumption was also that it's a cartesian coordinate system, but it's a good question to ask.

Comment: yup data is coming from x,y gird. Cartesian :)

Comment: How can this be made into a rails select statement.

Comment: You can use the order statement and put the SQL directly into that, and combine that with a limit statement: order("SQRT(POWER((X-x),2)+POWER((Y-y),2)) ASC").limit(20).  Just be sure to sanitize your SQL parameters if the input has a chance of SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using geolocated data. If your database backend is Postgres, check to see if you have or can install the PostGIS extensions. This gives you very fast tools which give you searches like 'search for the nearest thing to this point', 'search for everything within this circle', 'search for everything within this square', and so on.

http://postgis.refractions.net/

You would do something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX [indexname] ON [tablename] USING GIST ( [geometrycolumn] gist_geometry_ops);
```

Then you can do something like this - find everything within 100 metres of a point:

```
SELECT * FROM GEOTABLE WHERE
GEOM && GeometryFromText(’BOX3D(900 900,1100 1100)’,-1) AND
Distance(GeometryFromText(’POINT(1000 1000)’,-1),GEOM) < 100;
```

Examples from [the manual](http://www.geoconnections.org/developersCorner/devCorner_devNetwork/meetings/2002.05.30/postgis.pdf).